# Remove only one document in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

when I call

```
db.collection.remove({'condition':'some condition'});
```

This one line will delete all the matching condition documents.

What If I want to remove only one of any or n-th matching condition?

Comment: Why would you *want* to do that?  What's special about the one to delete that it should be removed but the others left?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to perform two separate queries for this

- take only one item from the matching filters

  ```
  var item = db.collection.findOne({'condition':'some condition'})
  ```
- and delete the item by using the id

  ```
   db.collection.remove({_id: item._id});
  ```

Answer (score 11):

`db.collection.remove` now has a `justOne` flag

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.remove/#db.collection.remove

Comment: Thanks arcyqwerty, the mongo API is really inconsistent, not sure why the boolean flag is 'multi' on updates and 'justOne' (the opposite) for remove...

Answer (score 2):

If there are multiple records and you want to delete only first record, then set justOne parameter in remove() method.

Here, you want to delete only 1. Thus, set "justOne" parameter as 1.

**db.collection.remove({'condition':'some condition'},1);**

Answer (score 2):

To remove one document from collection use the bellow command

db.collectionname.remove({"_id": ObjectId("5473293d43ecdre56352457f3a")})

Comment: That changing it into an object class was the kicker ! I had to use the var i used to require mongodb >   req.dogs.remove({ "_id", mongodb.ObjectId(req.params.id)}, function(err, ....

Answer (score 1):

### According to [MongoDB db.collection.remove() reference](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.remove/):

> #### justOne
>
> An optional boolean value. To limit the deletion to just one document, set to `true`. Omit to use the default value of `false` and delete all documents matching the deletion criteria.

You can set the `justOne` to `true`, in order to do it.

**Before** MongoDB version 2.6:

```
db.collection.remove(
   <query>,
   <justOne>
)
```

MongoDB version **2.6 or later**:

```
db.collection.remove(
   <query>,
   {
     justOne: <boolean>,
     writeConcern: <document>
   }
)
```

Like this: `db.collection.remove({"condition": "some condition"}, {justOne: true});`.

Answer (score 1):

I used this and it's worked for me

```
db.eventList.remove({"_id":ObjectId("5d9f3bd0c02cef7d50bb97fb")});
```

this is working on MongoDB shell version: 3.2.17

here eventList ===> collection

Comment: This is identical to an earlier answer. It gives nothing that wasn't already there.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just run a find first to get the id then a delete when you have the one you want?

Comment: I want to remove just one matching condition document while many documents are matching with single MongoDB command. Perhaps it does not exist?

Comment: I believe it's something people are asking for but to my knowledge it has not been implemented yet.

Comment: :\ I hope it to be implemented soon

Comment: Needing this feature is a schema smell. A feature that randomly deletes a document depending on unpredictable conditions such as b-tree walk direction is not going to be added (i hope).

Answer (score 0):

Try this one for delete.

```
db.users.deleteOne({"_id": ObjectId("5473293d43ecdre56352457f3a")});
```

Answer (score 0):

For example the name of the db is 'abc' and under that there's a collection by name 'users' and users has an email which is 'test@test.com' which you want to remove:
1. On the terminal if you type 'show dbs' (without quotation' ') it would list all the databases including 'abc'
2. If you type 'use abc', it would switch to your desired db - abc (with the message: "switched to db abc")
3. Now if you type 'show collections', it would show all the collections including 'users'
4. If you want to list all the documents in this collection, you simply type: db.users.find({})
5. If you want to delete a specific document in this collection, type:
db.users.remove({"email":"test@test.com"})

If it's successful, it would display - WriteResult({ "nRemoved" : 1 })