# Removing one record mongodb c# drive

Tags: c#, mongodb

I just want to remove one record in table "Meta" for example PasswordInfo
I tried this code:

```
var data = _mednoteDb.GetCollection(Users).FindOne(...);//specific record
data.Remove("PasswordInfo");
```

but it didin't work.

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aVSC4.png)

Comment: you should put your code in the question post, and if possible, put the post title in the form of a question.  this might be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7883871/remove-only-one-document-in-mongodb .  are you trying to delete a subdocument or the entire collection-level document?

Comment: I'm trying to remove subdocument

Comment: did my answer help you? did you figure out what you needed to?

Comment: I still can't remove subdocument, because my subdocument looks like this :"PracticeData" : "{id:1,name:Centrum ,phoneNumber:987798,nip:671}

Comment: Nevermind I solved problem $unset help me:  Database.GetCollection(Users).Update(query, Update.Unset("Meta.PasswordInfo"));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not a mongodb superexpert, but depending on the format of your data you might want to be using one or another of the mongodb operator functions.

`$pull` is the operator for deleting element from an array property of a document, [documentation here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/).

`$unset` is the operator for deleting subdocument from a document, [documentation here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/unset/).

There are a bunch of examples already on stackoverflow, if you don't find what you are search looking for, I can point you in some specific directions.