# How do i remove a certain value from array in mongodb(mongoose model)

Tags: node.js, arrays, mongodb, mongoose

I am doing a project to insert and delete several person in a room
Following is my schema

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const roomSchema=new Schema({
    Room_number:{
                   type:String,
                   required:true
                   },
    Roommates:{
                   type:Array,
                   default:[]
                   },
    Allocated: {
                    type:Boolean,
                    default:false
                     },
    Occupied:  {
                     type:Boolean,
                     default:false
                    },
    Batch:{
                     type:String
                    } ,
    position:{
                     type:String
                    }                                                               

},{
    versionKey: false // You should be aware of the outcome after set to false
})


var Room = mongoose.model('room', roomSchema);

module.exports = Room;
```

Here you can see that "Roommates" is an array,which contain name of people residing in that room like ["user1","user2","user3"]
so i need to delete a certain user from array,but i am not getting a mongodb command to Find and update it,i know push and pull but i don't know how to remove a specific value from array in a single command,i can do a for loop and find the value but i have doubts in commands to update the certain document.

Comment: checkout this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7883871/remove-only-one-document-in-mongodb

Comment: Do you need to remove an user in Roommates in all documents or filter the documents with some conditions?

Comment: yes i wanna remove a certain user in a certain room

Comment: @bhaginath no that's not it,i know how to remove a single document ,but the problem is how to remove one name in an array.

Comment: @AshwinJoshy could you please post sample data and the expected data in a json format.

Answer (score 0):

The right answer is

```
 Room.updateOne({ Room_number:room,Roommates:"Value i wanna find and delete or update" },{ $set: { "Roommates.$" :"here it find the firsts occurence in array and we can update by declaring here" } })
```

since this is updateOne ,only 1 name in array will be updated.
Roommates.$ will find first occurence of the result which is on Roommates array